# Text only being drawn on window resize

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have this code to create my html canvas header:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var canvas = document.getElementById('header-canvas'),
            context = canvas.getContext('2d');

        // resize the canvas to fill browser window dynamically
        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = 120;

            drawStuff();
        }
        resizeCanvas();

        function drawStuff() {
            var c = document.getElementById("header-canvas"),
                ctx = c.getContext("2d"),
                grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, 0, c.height),
                x = c.width / 2;
            y = c.height / 2;

            grd.addColorStop(0, "#0ac5f4");
            grd.addColorStop(1, "#7ae0fa");

            ctx.fillStyle = grd;
            ctx.fillRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);

            ctx.font = '30px LatoHL';
            ctx.textAlign = 'center';
            ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
            ctx.fillText('MACKENZIE GRAY', x, y);
        }
    })();
</script>
```

But my text is only showing up when I re-size the window... What is the issue with the function?

EDIT: I should add, the gradient does show up.

Answer (score 2):

It's because the `drawStuff()` function is only being called when your `resizeCanvas` function is called.  `resizeCanvas` is running when the resize event occurs in your window (see line: `window.addEventListener`)

To fix this, just run `drawStuff()` when your document loads.

Comment: I figured this may be the issue, but isn't the gradient being drawn in the drawStuff() function as well?

Comment: The code may be running before the document loads.  Try the [ready](http://api.jquery.com/ready/) function in jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

As Taylor Hayward commented, it could be that you are trying to render the text before the canvas has fully initialized. Put and `alert();` or a `console.log()` call in `drawStuff()` to see exactly when it is called.

If you find it is being called to early, try using jQuery `$(document).ready(...)`.